# Can you please explain me the following lines in below linkedlist C++ code:

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, c++17, singly-linked-list

Can you please **explain me the meaning of following  lines** in below **linked list** **code** and if you know any **alternate method to these lines** then please share it as well.

1. ListNode *l3=NULL;
2. ListNode **node=&l3;
3. (*node)=new ListNode(sum%10);
4. node=&((*node)->next);

I have also marked them in the code as **query 1, query2, query3** and **query 4** for your convinience

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */


class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        int sum=0;
        ListNode *l3=NULL; //----------------------------------Query 1
        ListNode **node=&l3;//---------------------------------Query 2
        while(l1!=NULL||l2!=NULL||sum>0)
        {
            if(l1!=NULL)
            {
                sum+=l1->val;
                l1=l1->next;
            }
            if(l2!=NULL)
            {
                sum+=l2->val;
                l2=l2->next;
            }
            (*node)=new ListNode(sum%10);//--------------------Query 3
            sum/=10;
            node=&((*node)->next);//---------------------------Query 4
        }        
        return l3;
    }
};
```

Comment: What exactly about these statements do you need help understanding?  Have you have a [decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) to reference for things like this?

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar What is unclear in this declaration ListNode *l3=NULL;?

Comment: Recommendation: Don't be THAT guy. Use descriptive variable names. If you chose identifiers that convey meaning, the code will usually explain itself.

Answer (score 2):

> ListNode *l3=NULL;

Declares a variable named `l3` of type `ListNode*`, and initializes it to `NULL`.

> ListNode **node=&l3;

Declares a variable named `node` of type `ListNode**`, and initializes it to point at the memory address of `l3`.

> (*node)=new ListNode(sum%10);

Dereferences `node` to access the current `ListNode*` it is pointing at, and then sets that pointer to point at a new `ListNode` object constructed with `sum%10` for its data.

> node=&((*node)->next);

Sets `node` to point at the memory address of the new `ListNode`'s `next` member.

This double-pointer trick is commonly used to keep track of the next `ListNode*` pointer that needs to be updated on each loop iteration, to avoid having to use an `if` statement and an extra variable, eg:

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ...
    ListNode *l3 = NULL, *last = NULL, *node;
    while (...)
    {
        ...
        node = new ListNode(...);
        ...
        if (l3 == NULL)
            l3 = node;
        else
            last->next = node;
        last = node;
    }        
    return l3;
}
```